# Does the old technique of kernel32.dll search (find .dll base address) not work anymore?

Tags: malware, exploit, antimalware, exploit-development

> Does the old technique of kernel32.dll search (find .dll base address) not work anymore?

In the code below, I first take the kernel32.dll (return) address when the application starts, and then attempt to locate its base.

The page size of the sytem - in this case Windows 10 x64 - is `4096` bytes, so the image base is aligned to a boundary of `0x1000`?

However, when I repeatedly decrease the (AND'd) address by `0x1000`, I suddenly get to the point of a memory segmentation error, and the base is not found.

Having studied the execution using GDB it seems that the last working address is:

```
0x74400010 <KERNEL32!BasepAppContainerEnvironmentExtension+0>: mov edi,edi
```

Can someone explain my observations?

Here is the code for kernel32.dll search:

```
mov ebx, [esp] ; kernel address
and ebx, 0xfffff000 ; align value (base is aligned to 0x1000)
mov ecx, 0x50 ; page counter

loop_api:

mov ax, "MZ"
cmp ax, word [ebx] ; check DOS header
je found_dos

next_api:
sub ebx, 0x1000 ; subtract on page
dec ecx
jnz loop_api
jmp exit_normal 

found_dos:
mov eax, ebx
add eax, [eax + 0x3c]
cmp word [eax], "PE" ; check PE header
jne next_api

found_kernel:
```

Comment: Rather strange, I don't *think* the base address has changed in any recent version or architecture, since that would break the compatibility with other Windows versions. To be certain, you could try to divide the executable in memory by the size of a `__int64` and hope first index on your array is the base address.

Comment: @YorickdeWid -- have you also tested it and do you experience the same problem? I'm not sure if I've misunderstood the method.

Comment: No I have not, this was just a wild guess

Comment: @YorickdeWid -- can you explain why your method might work?

Comment: Are we talking executable or dll? *big difference*

Comment: @YorickdeWid - We are talking about a program (executable) trying to locate the address of kernel32.dll, which has been loaded into its address space (by default).

Comment: Locating a shared object in memory is something different as finding the base address of an executable, which the question implies.

Comment: The question header mention "Finding kernel32.dll..."

Comment: Which got me confused with the additional data given in the comments, hence I asked: are we talking DLL or EXE?

Comment: We are talking about an EXE that wants to locate its loaded .DLL modules (in this case kernel32.dll). This is useful for malware, such program must locate API functions.